# Clicking on button, not working in React.Js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and bumped into below issue.

I have a file 'Cockpit.js' that has a component, being rendered in 'App.js'. There is an onClick event handler(below) :

```
<button className={btnClass} onClick={props.switch_name_handler1}>Switch 1</button>
```

applied to a button in file 'Cockpit.js', which is NOT working when clicked. There is no error in browser console or in the rendered HTML(when page is loaded OR button is clicked).

I tried to changed the order of 'event' parameter(placed it second to 'Rocky' parameter) being passed to the 'switchHandler' function after reading this article https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html, but that didn't work.

Below is the button code from file 'Cockpit.js' :

```
<button className={btnClass} onClick={props.switch_name_handler1}>Switch 1</button>
```

**complete code of 'Cockpit.js'** : http://freetexthost.com/k1c1t0565q

Below is the code from file 'App.js' from where I am sending 'switch_name_handler1' prop to the button in Cockpit.js) :

```
switch_name_handler1={(event) => this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, 'Rocky', event)}
```

**switchNameHandler** function defined in 'App.js' :

```
switchNameHandler = (newName, event) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        persons: 
          [
            {name : newName, age: 22},
            {name : 'Tony', age: 12}
          ]
      }
    )   
  }
```

**complete code of 'App.js'** :  http://freetexthost.com/su06cj5ijq

**complete code of 'Person.js' for reference** : http://freetexthost.com/zyxyzd23tv

I want to know the why the click is not working? It would be great if someone can suggest me the debugging steps for such cases(kind of points to keep in mind). If anything you feel is needed in this question please do let me know so that I can update the question. Thanks in advance!

**Update** :

I solved this issue by modifying 'Cockpit.js' file with button code as below(This was from the suggestion by [Vadim Hulevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10761855/vadim-hulevich).

```
Old : 

<button className={btnClass} onClick={props.switch_name_handler1}>Switch 1</button>

New : 
<button className={btnClass} onClick={(event) =>props.switch_name_handler1(event)}>Switch 1</button>
```

Also I removed the 'bind' from the props object I was passing to switch_name_handler1 in 'App.js' file as below :

```
Old : 

switch_name_handler1={(event) => this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, 'Rocky', event)}

New : 

switch_name_handler1={(event) => this.switchNameHandler('Rocky', event)}
```

I still don't know why it worked but would be great if someone can shed their thoughts on it.

Comment: try this :onClick={(e)=>props.switch_name_handler1(e)}

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing your full code - it's difficult to help you with only the partial snippets you've supplied.

Comment: @Vadim : Tried this but not working, no error in console or webpage(on clicking or reloading)

Comment: @IanKemp : I have updated question to add the links to complete code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Made a small working example for showing use case which might work well on your use case.

[CodeSandbox -demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q309mzq5ow)

Comment: Thanks for your demo but in my case I had the button in a different file('Cockpit.js') and the 'props' object was passed from 'App.js' whereas in demo all was in a single file. I have update my question with how I fixed it although I still don't know why it worked.